# Screen shivers on a fresh install

Tags: 10.10, drivers, ati

I have just installed Ubuntu 10.10 and after the installation when I logged in It Shivers from edges on High Resolution, and if I set the resolution to 800x600 it stops shivering, what's the problem? My board is Intel DGC101 and it has a built in ATI Radeon Xpress 200 Card. What should i do?

Comment: Did you install the proprietary driver (from Additional Drivers)?

Comment: Try what Toki suggested, though [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary#phrase). I've never had any luck with that chip set in Ubuntu. 'Course I gave up on running Ubuntu on my desktop in 2009.

Comment: @Toki as far as I know the Radeon Xpress 200 card is only supported by open ati drivers. @Ahsan what refresh rate is shown in the monitor section of your preferences menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a CRT or an LCD?  You are using the SVGA connector, not DVI right?  If this is an LCD and it has a DVI connector, you should use that instead of SVGA.  Does your monitor have a button that brings up the on screen status display that tells you the resolution and frequency it is running at?  Is it running at 60 Hz or 70 Hz?  What about in 800x600?

I had this happen to me once when I used a cable TV tuner card because there was a 48 volt 60 Hz AC signal on the line, which caused a small 60 Hz ripple on the ground plane.  If the monitor is running at 70 Hz, then it sets up a 10 Hz beat that scrambles the horizontal refresh signal and causes the edges of the monitor to wobble.  Running the monitor at 60 Hz stopped the wobble, but still left the edges annoyingly bent.  The DVI connector should be immune to this.